# Cert file vs Security Certificate

Tags: windows, ssl, openssl, xampp

Question : What is the difference between security certificate file .crt(Security Certificate) and .cert(CERT FILE)

Problem: I am trying to generate a self signed certificate wherein to be used to establish an SSL Connection using XAMPP , APACHE. The problem is that when im trying to use the .crt files for my generate certificate my web server(apache) is not getting started based on my apache_error.log :

```
[Mon Oct 24 17:29:24.358978 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 5712:tid 520] AH02577: Init: SSLPassPhraseDialog builtin is not supported on Win32 (key file D:/xampp/apache/conf/moodle1/cbcatmacdapp.cbcmain.chinabank.ph.key)
[Mon Oct 24 17:29:24.359976 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 5712:tid 520] AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. See D:/xampp/apache/logs/error.log for more information
[Mon Oct 24 17:29:24.359976 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 5712:tid 520] AH02564: Failed to configure encrypted (?) private key 172.20.189.183:443:0, check D:/xampp/apache/conf/moodle1/cbcatmacdapp.cbcmain.chinabank.ph.key
[Mon Oct 24 17:29:24.359976 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 5712:tid 520] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Mon Oct 24 17:29:24.359976 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 5712:tid 520] SSL Library Error: error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error
[Mon Oct 24 17:29:24.359976 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 5712:tid 520] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Mon Oct 24 17:29:24.359976 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 5712:tid 520] SSL Library Error: error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error (Type=RSA)
[Mon Oct 24 17:29:24.359976 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 5712:tid 520] SSL Library Error: error:04093004:rsa routines:OLD_RSA_PRIV_DECODE:RSA lib
[Mon Oct 24 17:29:24.359976 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 5712:tid 520] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Mon Oct 24 17:29:24.359976 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 5712:tid 520] SSL Library Error: error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error (Type=PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO)
AH00016: Configuration Failed
```

Comment: (1) Use 'code' formatting (the {} button or ctrl-K) for log files and similar line-oriented and fixed-width text; I editted for you (2) the log shows a problem with the .key file not any certificate file (3) it appears you are using an encrypted key file but that is not supported, so use an unencrypted key file

Comment: Hi @dave_thompson_085 thanks for the edit, but it will work if i declare nophrase for that key?.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)